# A nodejs web service serving REST api AND also being a consumer of a message queue

Tags: node.js, rest, architecture, microservices, message-queue

I am building an application and trying to follow best practices for microservice and currently learning about the topic of message queues and its' advantage over REST APIs.

My main question is, is it a bad idea to have a web service in the backend that serves externally facing REST APIs and at the same time it acts as a consumer of a message queue?

DETAILS:

I have a service called MyObjectService in NodeJS, and its' externally facing REST API is a simple GET on MyObject residing in a database. I have two other services that wants to update the status of MyObject and rather than connecting the two other services directly to the database to update the objects, I want to queue an update of the object for the MyObjectService to consume, which then the MyObjectService will update MyObject in the database. This would help with availability and loose coupling.

Is this bad practice, especially with NodeJS (due to single threaded aspect of NodeJS?), and the right solution is to have two separate services that one GETs MyObject and the other UPDATEs MyObject? Or is what I am describing totally possible?

I would appreciate any thoughts on this. Thank you.

Comment: I used RabbitMQ once to add messaging support to a NodeJS app https://www.devbridge.com/articles/messaging-with-rabbitmq-in-node-js/

Comment: The best practice is for same endpoint to be responsible for serving and updating the object. You use `GET` for reading the object and `PUT` for updating it.